# Can I lay out 3 elements to that middle element floats left?

Tags: css, flexbox

My content management software is imposing rigidity on how my elements are parsed on the page, and I'm stuck with something like the following HTML:

```html
<div class="section-container">
  <h4>Title Coming In from Content Mgmt</h4>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="some_product_img" />
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph-container">
    <p>Some product information blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not much I can do about that. But my design requires a layout like such:
[image]

Given that I cannot change the HTML structure here, is there some kind of CSS wizardry that will allow me to achieve the desired layout?

I have experimented with using `float`s and tried some flexbox tricks like `flex-basis`, but reached a plateau in my knowledge and second-guessed if it were possible with those methods.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: would display:grid be fine for you ?

Comment: That might just do the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display:grid is nowdays the easiest way for this kind of layout

example

```css
.section-container {
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:auto 1fr;
}
.image-container {
grid-row:1 /span 2;
grid-column:1;
}
/* see us */.section-container > *{border:solid rgb(44, 124, 254);margin:2px;}
```

```html
<div class="section-container">
  <h4>Title Coming In from Content Mgmt</h4>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/200" />
  </div>
  <div class="paragraph-container">
    <p>Some product information blah blah blah</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is a couple of usefull links https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/  &  https://gridbyexample.com/